# Installing cudatoolkit 8.0 with anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

In order to run some old Tensorflow code (version 1.4.1), I need to install the Cuda 8 runtime.

I decided the easiest way must be using Anaconda, and my searching has shown that Anaconda at least *used to* provide a package `cudatoolkit ver. 8.0`, but this does not seem to be the case anymore. Is there any way to install an older package like this through Anaconda? I have done this for other earlier CUDA/TF versions, and it is nice to be able to manage the versions of each in a single environment for running certain legacy codebases.

Comment: You can refer these links for CUDA toolkit version 8, https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive and https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to install Tensorflow 1.4.1 with cudatoolkit 8.0, with the following command:

```
mamba create -n parsim python=3 "tensorflow-gpu=1.4" pillow opencv -c shuangnan -c anaconda
```

(see [Weird `glibc==2.17` conflict when trying to conda install tensorflow 1.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71546900/weird-glibc-2-17-conflict-when-trying-to-conda-install-tensorflow-1-4-1))